# How to properly organize iterators for my container

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement iterators for my container, but something tells me that I'm on the wrong path, I'd like to hear how to implement constants and reverse iterators correctly.

At the moment I stopped at such an implementation, but unfortunately I get an error.

```
error: cannot convert 'Node<int>*' to 'Node<const int>*' in initialization
   73 | Iterator<Type>::Iterator(Node<TypeIter>* n_ptr) : data(n_ptr)
```

implementation

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
class Node
{
public:
    Type element;
    Node<Type>* prev;
    Node<Type>* next;
public:
    Node() : element(), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {};
    Node(const Type& elem, Node* prev, Node* next) : element(elem), prev(prev), next(next) {};
    Node(const Node& node) : Node(node.element, node.prev, node.next) {};
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
class Iterator
{
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<Type>;
    using pointer = Type*;
    using reference = Type&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
public:
    Node<Type>* data;
public:
    explicit Iterator(Node<Type>* ptr = nullptr);
    Iterator(const Iterator& iterator);

    template<typename TypeIter>
    explicit Iterator(Node<TypeIter>* ptr = nullptr);
    template<typename TypeIter>
    explicit Iterator(const Iterator<TypeIter>& iterator);

    ~Iterator() = default;

    bool operator==(const Iterator& lhs) const;
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs) const;

    Iterator operator++();
    Iterator operator++(int post);
    Iterator operator--();
    Iterator operator--(int post);

    Type& operator*();
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace std
{
    template <typename Type>
    struct iterator_traits<Iterator<Type>>
    {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<Type>;
        using pointer = Type*;
        using reference = Type&;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_concept = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
    };
} // namespace std
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
template <typename Type>
class Deque
{
public:
    //Using
    using iterator = Iterator<Type>;
    using const_iterator = Iterator<const Type>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
```

As far as I understand it is connected with the fact that I have 2 different templates one with const and the other without.

```
    using iterator = Iterator<Type>;
    using const_iterator = Iterator<const Type>;
```

[Complete code](https://pastebin.com/meZxWTqR)

main

```
int main()
{
    Deque<int> test;
    test.push_back(123);
    test.push_back(77);
    test.push_back(1);
    test.push_back(777);
    test.push_back(321);
    test.push_back(111);
    test.push_back(12);
    test.push_back(1000);

    std::cout << test.front() << '\n';
    std::cout << test.back() << '\n';
    std::cout << "==========" << '\n';

    auto [min_it, max_it] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(test), std::end(test));
    std::cout << *min_it << " - " << *max_it << '\n';

    auto [min_it1, max_it1] = std::minmax_element(std::rbegin(test), std::rend(test));
    std::cout << *min_it1 << " - " << *max_it1 << '\n';

    auto [min_it2, max_it2] = std::minmax_element(std::cbegin(test), std::cend(test));
    std::cout << *min_it2 << " - " << *max_it2 << '\n';    

    Deque<int>::const_iterator cIter;
    std::cout << "The const itr deque is: ( ";
    for (cIter = test.cbegin(); cIter != test.cend(); ++cIter)
    {
        std::cout << *Iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << ")." << std::endl;
```

Comment: Those `Iterator` constructor templates look odd. How would you expect to create e.g. an `Iterator<int>` from any instantiation of `Node` or `Iterator`?

Comment: @rustyx Done. Added.

Comment: @molbdnilo So I would like to get a small example of how this could be implemented normally.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/stl_interfaces.html might wanna have a look at this